# twitter stream api filter_level

Tags: api, twitter, stream

I can't find any reference about the twitter stream api `filter_level` when I want to follow some accounts using user stream.

I know `none` means no filter, but I keep get retweets from other people when I set `filter_level` as `low`, when I set the `filter_level` to `medium`, I can't get anything from it. Anybody could tell me what filters does each `filter_level` mean.

Comment: [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters) tells us: Setting this parameter to one of none, low, or medium will set the minimum value of the filter_level Tweet attribute required to be included in the stream. The default value is none, which includes all available Tweets. 

When displaying a stream of Tweets to end users (dashboards or live feeds at a presentation or conference, for example) it is suggested that you set this value to medium.  What isn't clear about that? :)

Comment: I mean I want to know what is the condition for each filter.

Comment: @ShawnMehan The question was very clear. It is not straightforward what tweets you get when the filter_level is medium or low..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter measures the importance of a tweet using this parameter.It is a rating that Twitter gives to its tweets. A tweet with `filter_level=high` is identified as more important ( a part of @toptweets concept ).

If you set `filter_level=low`, then you are asking for tweets with low, medium and high filter levels.You set the minimum quality of the tweets that you want using `filter_level`.

This is a useful resource: https://thenextweb.com/twitter/2013/02/14/twitter-adds-language-info-ability-to-filter-tweets-by-importance-with-new-metadata/